# How to declare BruteForceMatcher in OPENCV 3.x C++ Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.0

I'm using Open CV 3.2 and work in Visual Studio 2015 Platform.

In [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/user_guide/ug_features2d.html) they use BruteForceMatcher.

And based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389307/opencv-3-0-0-surffeaturedetector-and-surfdescriptorextractor-errors), I know there are several differences of using opencv 2.x and 3.x.

So, is there any suggestion how to change

```
BruteForceMatcher<L2<float> > matcher;
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
```

into Open CV 3.x form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following code

```
Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher(new cv::BFMatcher(cv::NORM_HAMMING, true));
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher->match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
```